# Can I give my gun to a friend with no paperwork in any state?

Tags: united-states, firearms

If I lawfully own a gun, are there any states where I can give it to another person legally without any paperwork?

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: The question could be interpreted as 'please help me commit a crime and get away with it' which probbly triggered the close votes.

Comment: @quarague Oh! That seems quite an extreme interpretation!

Comment: @quarague Even if the OP is thinking about actually transfering a gun (which is not clear cut from the question), he is just asking if it is legal or illegal, not how to avoid getting caught doing something illegal. If it is legal in OP's state, there would be no crime. If it illegal, answering the OP that "at state X you must fill forms 1, 2 or 3" might help him to fill those forms (and avoid the crime from happening) and, in any case, would not help the OP to not fill the forms.

Comment: @SJuan76 I think someone might have been speculating about the motivation to want to get rid of a gun without any paper trail.

Answer (score 4):

First, one must comply with Federal law: 18 U.S.C. §922(a)(5)(A) which makes it unlawful to transfer a firearm when the transferor and transferee are not both residents of the same state. "It shall be unlawful . . ."

> (5) for any person (other than a licensed importer, licensed
> manufacturer, licensed dealer, or licensed collector) to transfer,
> sell, trade, give, transport, or deliver any firearm to any person
> (other than a licensed importer, licensed manufacturer, licensed
> dealer, or licensed collector) who the transferor knows or has
> reasonable cause to believe does not reside in (or if the person is a
> corporation or other business entity, does not maintain a place of
> business in) the State in which the transferor resides; except that
> this paragraph shall not apply to (A) the transfer, transportation, or
> delivery of a firearm made to carry out a bequest of a firearm to, or
> an acquisition by intestate succession of a firearm by, a person who
> is permitted to acquire or possess a firearm under the laws of the
> State of his residence, and (B) the loan or rental of a firearm to any
> person for temporary use for lawful sporting purposes;

If both persons are residents of the same state but the intended recipient is a "prohibited person" under the Gun Control Act of 1968 and the transferor knows it or has reason to believe it, private transfer would be a criminal act under 18 U.S.C. § 922(d):

> (d) It shall be unlawful for any person to sell or otherwise dispose
> of any firearm or ammunition to any person knowing or having
> reasonable cause to believe that such person, including as a juvenile—
> (1) is under indictment for, or has been convicted in any court of, a
> crime punishable by imprisonment for a term exceeding one year; (2) is
> a fugitive from justice; (3) is an unlawful user of or addicted to any
> controlled substance (as defined in section 102 of the Controlled
> Substances Act (21 U.S.C. 802)); (4) has been adjudicated as a mental
> defective or has been committed to any mental institution at 16 years
> of age or older; (5) who, being an alien— (A) is illegally or
> unlawfully in the United States; or (B) except as provided in
> subsection (y)(2), has been admitted to the United States under a
> nonimmigrant visa (as that term is defined in section 101(a)(26) of
> the Immigration and Nationality Act (8 U.S.C. 1101(a)(26))); (6)
> who [2] has been discharged from the Armed Forces under dishonorable
> conditions; (7) who, having been a citizen of the United States, has
> renounced his citizenship; (8) is subject to a court order that
> restrains such person from harassing, stalking, or threatening an
> intimate partner of such person or child of such intimate partner or
> person, or engaging in other conduct that would place an intimate
> partner in reasonable fear of bodily injury to the partner or child,
> except that this paragraph shall only apply to a court order that— (A)
> was issued after a hearing of which such person received actual
> notice, and at which such person had the opportunity to participate;
> and (B) (i) includes a finding that such person represents a credible
> threat to the physical safety of such intimate partner or child; or
> (ii) by its terms explicitly prohibits the use, attempted use, or
> threatened use of physical force against such intimate partner or
> child that would reasonably be expected to cause bodily injury; (9)
> has been convicted in any court of a misdemeanor crime of domestic
> violence; (10) intends to sell or otherwise dispose of the firearm or
> ammunition in furtherance of a felony, a Federal crime of terrorism,
> or a drug trafficking offense (as such terms are defined in section
> 932(a)); or (11) intends to sell or otherwise dispose of the firearm
> or ammunition to a person described in any of paragraphs (1) through
> (10). This subsection shall not apply with respect to the sale or
> disposition of a firearm or ammunition to a licensed importer,
> licensed manufacturer, licensed dealer, or licensed collector who
> pursuant to subsection (b) of section 925 is not precluded from
> dealing in firearms or ammunition, or to a person who has been granted
> relief from disabilities pursuant to subsection (c) of section 925.

Finally, if no federal law bars such a transfer, then yes, many states -- I'd say the majority of U.S. states -- allow the private transfer of a firearm between private individual residents of their state with no paperwork. Some states such as my state, New Hampshire, require a transferor to actually know the transferee for the transfer of a handgun, but that's not a requirement for a long gun.

To learn the legality of undocumented private transfer in any particular state, use a search engine to ask **[state name] gun laws**. It's all out there.

It is a simple matter to perform a firearm transfer through a Federal Firearms Licensee (FFL) with payment of a fee and a background check on the recipient, who must be a resident of the same state as the place of business of the FFL. Paperwork is involved.

Comment: "Finally, if no federal law bars such a transfer, then yes, many states -- I'd say the majority of U.S. states -- allow the private transfer of a firearm between private individual residents of their state with no paperwork" Do you know any of these states?

Comment: @Simd I mentioned NH above. From personal recollection, Maine too but not Vermont. Texas, Utah and Arizona but not Colorado or New Mexico. Oregon to family members only, but not friends. Idaho is OK but not Washington. You can Google any others that you are interested in.

Comment: @MTA What constitutes a transfer?  If my out of state friend comes over for some target shooting and I let him use my gun, have I transferred it to him?  What if I let him take it back to his hotel for the duration of his stay?  Does it become a transfer when we are no longer together?  Or, does a transfer mean the transfer of ownership -- ie. I gift it to him or sell it to him and no longer consider it mine?  What if I let him borrow it indefinitely, but I expect to get it back at some point, would that be a transfer?  Just curious as to exactly what transfer means practically.

Comment: @mikem IANAL, but the law quoted above states that "the loan or rental of a firearm to any person for temporary use for lawful sporting purposes" is not a transfer. So lending a gun for a 1-week hunting trip or 2-month African safari or a 3-day shooting match is not a transfer. Lending a gun "till whenever" without a demonstrable connection to a lawful sporting event would constitute a transfer under the above law. I'm sure there is case law on the subject for your further investigation.